# How to achieve this type of an effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I am trying to do something like this. Can someone tell me which technique has been used to get this effect in the picture?

[image: cutout girl]

Comment: Very basic photoshop mask with 2 photos, question lacks research.

Answer (score 5):

There are two main routes to achieve this kind of effect:

1. Use the rubber stamp tool to retouch out the parts of the figure that you don't want. (Tricky, time consuming and almost certainly NOT how this was achieved.)
2. Take two photographs, with your camera in a fixed position on a tripod, one with the figure present and one without and then overlay the two images in photoshop and use a layer mask to only show the parts that you require. (Probaly how this example image was done.)

Comment: I recommend step 2, for sure.  Easiest and best result.

Answer (score -2):

Yep, exactly what Chris said... most likely achieved with 2 photographs. 1 with the female against the wall, then another without her. Select the areas you want 'erased' and mask them out.

Comment: You're just repeating the other answer. Please only add constructive answers. If you want to know more about the site, check the [help].

Comment: Hi Scott. As Luciano's saying, we are a Q&A site, not a forum, so we don't like one answer repeating another. Once you have sufficient reputation (from upvotes on your posts), you can upvote others' posts to show support or agreement. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!